# Splitting a graph into two isomorphic parts

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, graph-isomorphism

Say a graph $G$ has $2n$ vertices.  I'd like to know if I can partition the vertices of $G$ into two parts $X$ and $Y$ such that $G[X]$ is isomorphic to $G[Y]$ ($G[S]$ denotes the subgraph of $G$ induced by $S \subseteq V(G)$).

Has anyone ever encountered this problem ?  I'm interested in any kind of characterization of graphs for which it is possible (or not), and on the hardness of problem.  It's probably NP-Hard but why ?

Comment: Considering that splitting a finite set of integers into two parts with the same sum is NP-complete, I'd be surprised if this graph problem isn't. Have you looked in Garey & Johnson?

Comment: I think there is something about this problem in Sabine Bachl, Isomorphic Subgraphs, pp 286-296 of the book Graph Drawing: 7th International Symposium, GD’99 Štiřín Castle, Czech Republic September 15–19, 1999 Proceedings, edited by Jan Kratochvíyl, http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-46648-7_30 (but there may be a paywall there).

Comment: Many thanks !  My University is fine with the paywall :)  Actually from what I understand, what they study in this paper is whether there exist two disjoint subsets $X$ and $Y$ of $V(G)$ such that $G[X]$ is isomorphic to $G[Y]$ and both graphs have at least $k$ edges.   Of course it's NP-Complete.  There are many similarities with the partioning problem - I'll guess I'll try to find a reduction.